# Ajax form redirects although preventDefault() is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my first question posted here, so I apologize in advance if the formatting is not quite as it should be. I am new to JS, and I have now encountered a problem that I have not been able to solve despite extensive use of Google.

I have a dynamically created form, and when that form is submitted I want to add the result to a div and not be redirected. I have tried using both event.preventDefault() and return false; but none of them work. The ajax call works correctly, because the result is visible for a short moment before the redirection. I would appreciate any help with this. This is my JS-code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#voteForm', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(event.type);
    var choice=$('input[name=choice]:checked').val();
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "submitVote.php",
        data: choice,
        success: function(result){
            $("#testDiv").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

The HTML-form:

```
<form id='voteForm' action='javascript:void(0)' method='POST'><!--Changed to action='javascript:void(0)' which made it work-->
    <input type='radio' name='choice' value='voteChoice1' checked='checked'>Yes<br />
    <input type='radio' name='choice' value='voteChoice2'>No<br />
    <input type='submit' id='submitButton' name='submitButton' value='Send'>
</form>
```

Comment: Can we see forms HTML markup?

Comment: This looks fine. What happens if you put `action="javascript:void(0)"` in the form?

Comment: Thank you! javascript:void(0) did the trick!

Comment: Care to try event.stopPropagation()?

Comment: event.stopPropagation() doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

event.preventDefault() works against submit handler, according to documentation: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

for "on" event handler you should try event.stopPropagation()

Although the better way would be to do it via jquery-form plugin. See function "ajaxForm" in their [online documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api). It does exactly what you want.

Comment: The ajax form plugin may do exactly what he wants, however, so should his current code.

Comment: I corrected my answer. Returning false indeed would not work - the documented way is to use preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

This event binding doesn't look right, try binding the submit event directly to the *form* instead of the document:

```
$("#voteForm").on("submit", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    alert("event captured");
    ...
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4PTdt/2/

Comment: but OP seems to need to use delegation

Comment: This makes no difference and if the form is infact created dynamically as the OP said then it won't work.

Comment: I tried that too, but it doen't work. Using $(document).on('submit'...) is the only way I have managed the ajax call to work.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the form is added dynamically or not, as long as the ID exists in the DOM when the event is bound, the event will be captured.

Comment: Thanks for providing HTML, I have updated the fiddle.

Comment: "It doesn't matter if the form is added dynamically or not, as long as the ID exists in the DOM when the event is bound, the event will be captured" That's incorrect. If the ID exists on an element, you bind an event to it, then you remove that element and just add another one back with the same ID, there's no event bound to it. Also, if the form is being added dynamically there's a good chance the ID doesn't exist when the event binding code is executed. There's nothing wrong with the code they've written, you're obviously just not familiar with event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

At they and of your function just add the following line "return false;". This will stop the form from submitting.

Comment: I have tried that, but it didn't work. It was still redirecting.